# How can I create a component-based message handling system with traits?

Tags: oop, scala, types

Here's a short example of what I want to do:

```
abstract class Message()
case class FooMessage() extends Message
case class BarMessage() extends Message
//... other messages ...

trait Component
{
  def handleMessage(msg: Message):Unit
}

trait ComponentType1 extends Component
{
  abstract override def handleMessage(msg: FooMessage) = {
    //handle foo, pass it up the chain
    super.handleMessage(msg)
  }

  abstract override def handleMessage(msg: BarMessage) = {
    //handle bar, pass it up the chain
    super.handleMessage(msg)
  }
}

//handles some other messages, also might handle the same messages as ComponentType1
trait ComponentType2 extends Component { .. }
```

Then, these `ComponentType`s are **mixed in** to a class to form an object that is completely composed of modular components.

I have a bunch of different `Message`s and a bunch of different `Component`s.

- Not all components handle all message types.
- Multiple components can handle the same message type.

  - The message cascades up through the components, even if it's handled by another component.
- A Component can handle more than one message type.

The problem is since `handleMessage` is defined in `Component` as accepting a `Message`, when I try to specialize the `msg` parameter it doesn't count as an override.

I know one possible solution to this is to declare a big `handleMessage` method with a big match statement, but I'd like to define a method per message if possible.

Comment: I think you either get mind-twisting type hackery or big match. Why you don't want to use partial functions? Note that they're easily composable using orElse method.

Comment: @CheatEx: I didn't say anything about not wanting to use partial functions. How would you use them here?

Comment: See below for an example using partial functions.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a partial function based solution.  Tip to CheatEx for the idea.

```
trait Message   
class FooMessage extends Message 
class BarMessage extends Message 

abstract class Component {
  type CPF = PartialFunction[Message, Unit]

  var pf: CPF  = { case _ => }

  def handleMessage(msg: Message) = pf(msg)
}

trait ComponentType1 extends Component {
  val ct1pf: CPF = {
    case msg: FooMessage => println("foo1")
    case msg: BarMessage => println("bar1")
  }
  pf = ct1pf orElse pf
}

trait ComponentType2 extends Component {
  val parentPf = pf
  val ct2pf: CPF = {
    case msg: 
      BarMessage => println("bar2")
      parentPf(msg)    // cascade 
  }
  pf = ct2pf orElse pf
}

object component1and2 extends ComponentType1 with ComponentType2

component1and2.handleMessage(new FooMessage)
component1and2.handleMessage(new BarMessage)
```

prints

```
foo1
bar2
bar1
```

Comment: Oh... I've wrote almost full answer.

Comment: One note: it is posiible to write handle message like `def handleMessage(msg: Message):Unit = if (pf.isDefinedAt(msg)) pf(msg)` and avoid `case _`

Comment: Another question. The OP wanted the messages to be handled and cascade down. So, presumably, the output for handling `new BarMessage` should be 'bar2bar1' (since ComponentType2 has precedence in your example). Is it possible to implement pf as a method and get it to call `super.pf`?

Comment: @GKelly Yes, you just need to replace `val` with `def` in the pf definition. But i think approach suggested by @ericacm is better, since you have named message handlers instead of nameless `super` calls.

Comment: I appreciate all your effort, but this is no different from using stackable traits and a match statement for each, which would be cleaner anyway.

Comment: That is true, they would be equivalent.  This was an experiment to see what it would look like. Sounds like you already knew what to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
trait Message   
class FooMessage extends Message 
class BarMessage extends Message 

trait Component {
  def handleMessage(msg: Message) {}
  def handleMessage(msg: FooMessage) {}
  def handleMessage(msg: BarMessage) {}
}

trait ComponentType1 extends Component {
  override def handleMessage(msg: FooMessage) = println("foo1")
  override def handleMessage(msg: BarMessage) = println("bar1")
}

trait ComponentType2 extends Component {
  override def handleMessage(msg: BarMessage) = println("bar2")
}

object component1and2 extends ComponentType1 with ComponentType2

component1and2.handleMessage(new FooMessage)
component1and2.handleMessage(new BarMessage)
```

prints

```
foo1
bar2
```

If you had a list somewhere of all the components in the system you could do

```
componentList.foreach(c => c.handleMessage(msg))
```

It would just no-op in Component for the components that didn't handle msg.

Comment: Updated to include the mixin stuff that you added.

Comment: What benefit does the visitor pattern provide over my method? The downside to both my method and your implementation is you have to define an empty method for each message type in the base component trait.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something. You have 2 methods in `Component` - one for each `Message`. This is what I was trying to avoid. If I did that in my implementation, it would work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:

```
trait Message   
class FooMessage extends Message 
class BarMessage extends Message 

trait Component {
  def handleMessage(msg: Message) {}
}

trait ComponentType1 extends Component {
  def handleMessage(msg: Message) {
    msg match {
      case m: FooMessage => println("foo1")
      case m: BarMessage => println("bar1")
      case _ => super.handleMessage(msg)
    }
  }
}

trait ComponentType2 extends Component {
  override def handleMessage(msg: Message) {
    msg match {
      case m: BarMessage =>
        println("bar2")
        super.handleMessage(m)    // cascade 
      case _ => super.handleMessage(msg)
    }
  }
}

object component1and2 extends ComponentType1 with ComponentType2

component1and2.handleMessage(new FooMessage)
component1and2.handleMessage(new BarMessage)
```

prints

```
foo
bar2
bar1
```